# Create list of high and low dates from single date in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of single dates that I need to extract time frames from.

example:

```
2014-02-27  
2015-04-06  
2016-01-31
```

I would like to see time frames:

Low Date to High Date

```
1900-01-01 2014-02-07  
2014-02-07 2015-04-06  
2015-04-06 2016-01-31  
2016-01-31 2017-02-28(Current end of month)
```

I have tried using LAG and LEAD in CASE statements. This Gets me close but not the desired result as shown in the example above.

How can I achieve this?

```
CASE WHEN lag(convert(date,ARD),1) OVER (Partition by InternalID,EpisodeSys,
groupersys ORDER by InternalID,EpisodeSys, [ARD],groupersys) is null then '1900-01-01' 
     WHEN lag(convert(date,ARD),1) OVER (Partition by InternalID,EpisodeSys,groupersys ORDER by InternalID,EpisodeSys,[ARD],groupersys) is not null and lag(convert(date,ARD),1) OVER (Partition by InternalID,EpisodeSys,groupersys/*,[ARD]*/ ORDER by InternalID,EpisodeSys,[ARD],groupersys) is not null then convert(Date,[ARD]) 
     ELSE convert(date,[ARD]) END as 'Low Date'
```

This code returns the correct table. Thank You! I really appreciate it.

```
SELECT distinct InternalID
            , episodesys
            , lag([ARD], 1, '1900-01-01') over 
                      (partition by groupersys 
                       order by [ARD], groupersys) as 'Low Date'
            ,[ARD] as 'High Date'
            , groupersys
            , RugsCatg
            ,CASE 
                WHEN lag([ARD], 1, '1900-01-01') over 
                        (partition by groupersys 
                         order by [ARD],groupersys) = '1900-01-01' 
                then 'A1'
                ELSE rug_source
            END as 'rug_source'
    FROM (SELECT InternalID,episodesys, [ARD],groupersys, RugsCatg, 'A2' as  rug_source 
          FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[assessment_detail]
          UNION 
          SELECT InternalID,episodesys, EOMONTH(GETDATE()),groupersys, RugsCatg, 'A3' as rug_source 
          FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[assessment_detail]
     ) T
         where episodesys = '668955'
```

Thank you again @JuanCarlosOropeza

This is how the data look when I run the code. These are the correct results.

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+  
| InternalID | episodesys |  Low Date  | High Date  | groupersys | RugsCatg | rug_source |  
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+  
| ABC123456  |     668955 | 1900-01-01 | 2016-09-07 |         51 | RUB      | A1         |  
| ABC123456  |     668955 | 1900-01-01 | 2016-09-07 |         57 | RUB      | A1         |  
| ABC123456  |     668955 | 2016-09-07 | 2016-09-14 |         51 | RUB      | A2         |  
| ABC123456  |     668955 | 2016-09-07 | 2016-09-14 |         57 | RUB      | A2         |  
| ABC123456  |     668955 | 2016-09-14 | 2017-02-28 |         51 | RUB      | A3         |  
| ABC123456  |     668955 | 2016-09-14 | 2017-02-28 |         57 | RUB      | A3         |  
+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

I created a view and put in the code. A SELECT from VIEW returns this. These are not the correct results. They are not the same as directly from the query.

```
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+  
|  InternalID  | episodesys |  Low Date  | High Date  | groupersys | RugsCatg | rug_source |  
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+  
| 1203V0023697 |       6689 | 2016-09-06 | 2016-09-07 |         51 | RUB      | A2         |  
| 1203V0023697 |       6689 | 2016-09-06 | 2016-09-07 |         57 | RUB      | A2         |  
| 1203V0023697 |       6689 | 2016-09-13 | 2016-09-14 |         51 | RUB      | A2         |  
| 1203V0023697 |       6689 | 2016-09-13 | 2016-09-14 |         57 | RUB      | A2         |  
| 1203V0023697 |       6689 | 2016-12-27 | 2017-02-28 |         51 | RUB      | A3         |  
| 1203V0023697 |       6689 | 2016-12-27 | 2017-02-28 |         57 | RUB      | A3         |  
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------------+
```

Why does it return this set of data?

Comment: Show us what have you try and what result you got.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: <code>,CASE 
   WHEN lag(convert(date,ARD),1) OVER (Partition by InternalID,EpisodeSys,groupersys ORDER by InternalID,EpisodeSys,[ARD],groupersys) is null then '1900-01-01'
   WHEN lag(convert(date,ARD),1) OVER (Partition by InternalID,EpisodeSys,groupersys ORDER by InternalID,EpisodeSys,[ARD],groupersys) is not null and lag(convert(date,ARD),1) OVER (Partition by InternalID,EpisodeSys,groupersys/*,[ARD]*/ ORDER by InternalID,EpisodeSys,[ARD],groupersys) is not null then convert(Date,[ARD])
  ELSE   
   convert(date,[ARD])
   END as 'Low Date' </code>

Comment: fmogo, dont put code in the comments, just update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eba87/8)**

Just add the current date as part of the data, and then Lag can include a default value in case `NULL`

```
SELECT lag([dt], 1, '1900-01-01') over (order by [dt]) as [low],
       [dt] as [high]
FROM (SELECT [dt] FROM Table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT GETDATE()
     ) T
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|                        low |                       high |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|  January, 01 1900 00:00:00 | February, 27 2014 00:00:00 |
| February, 27 2014 00:00:00 |    April, 06 2015 00:00:00 |
|    April, 06 2015 00:00:00 |  January, 31 2016 00:00:00 |
|  January, 31 2016 00:00:00 | February, 20 2017 20:45:35 |
```

Comment: I have tried to use the code you showed with all the fields but it returns inconsistent results.

Comment: what you mean `inconsistent results`? feel free to update the sqlfiddle demo with more data and show me what is the problem.

Comment: What are you using to format the results and the code?

Comment: nothing, just print as date. That bother you? want me to change to `yyyy-mm-dd` ?

Comment: The format of the date does not bother me.  I am concerned with the different output on the two tables.

Comment: can you elaborate what is the problem?